# How do I include a Swift framework project in another project in the same workspace

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios-frameworks

I've got a workspace setup with a hierarchy of projects, we'll call them 'A', 'B', and 'C'.

Project 'C' is a C++ project that compiles to a static library - no problem here.

Project 'B' is a mixed Swift / Obj-C framework that links project 'C' as a dependency. This works and the framework compiles on its own just fine.

Now the problem:
Project 'A' is an iOS project that includes 'B' as a linked binary library in it's Build Phases. When I try to compile 'A' I get build errors from the Obj-C bridging header in project 'B' that the headers cannot be found.

It seems that when I have a target from 'A' selected, the framework in project 'B' is being built using build settings from project 'A'. Ok, fine. I tried adding 'B's directory as a `User Header Search Path`. When I do this  and try to build 'A' I get errors about duplicate definitions of classes that are compiled as part of 'B' in classes in 'A' that `import B`, and the duplicate definitions originate from the included header in 'B's Obj-C bridging header.

I have the headers in the framework configured to copy to the framework's `Public` headers. If I move them from `Public` back to `Project` and include 'B's headers in the `User Header Search Path` in 'A', I don't have this problem.

I'm sure there's just some configuration somewhere that I'm missing but I don't know what it is.

How can I have a project build as a framework in the same workspace as my main application and include it as an independent, self-contained (headers coped, etc) dependency within my main iOS application?

Comment: In the `General` tab under your app (project A) target, is Project B listed in the `Embedded Binaries` section near the bottom?

Comment: @digitalHound yes it is, along with all the other dependency frameworks & libraries. None of the other ones are projects that are part of this workspace though - just Project B

Comment: Dunno about Objc, but adding as an Embedded binary is enough if the framework is Swift-only - only importing then is necessary. How objc complicates things no idea.